# RFC2396 - what is valid path segment?

Tags: java, http, rfc

### Problem area

I need to define whether a particular *path segment* is valid against [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). The spec says:

```
path_segments = segment *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar *( ";" param )
param         = *pchar
pchar         = unreserved | escaped | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
unreserved    = alphanum | mark
mark          = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"
escaped       = "%" hex hex
hex           = digit | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" |
                        "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f"
```

So, for example, `/foo` is a valid path segment but `/fo?o` isn't because of non-escaped `?`. To correct the above example, the path segment should be written as `/fo%3Fo`.

Spec, however, only defines validity of URIs that arrive at server (think: typed in the URL bar).

What I actually need to validate is whether **unescaped** path segment is valid. Continuing above example, `/fo?o` would be a valid resource as `?` is what you get when unescaping `%3F`.

This also means that URL `http://foo.com/first/sec%2fond` would resolve to two unescaped path segments, `/first` and `/sec/ond`, and the latter not only has to be treated as a **single** segment rather than two separate ones but is also syntactically valid (as an unescaped path segment).

### Questions

- do I correctly understand the spec?
- can anyone suggest a Java validator for *unescaped* path segments?
- can anyone suggest a non-trivial failing case?
- how about characters above U+00FF, can they not be used in path segments? I thought they were supported, at least in the domain names.

EDIT: as Mike correctly pointed out, RFC3986 obsoleted RFC2396. Anyway, I believe the new RFC handles more cases than the old (and doesn't make some path segments illegitimate) hence the same questions apply.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using RFC 2396 and not RFC 3986 which obsoletes 2396?  From RFC 3986 : "Obsoletes: 2732, 2396, 1808"

Comment: You’re wrong; `/first/sec%2fond` would result in three segments: an empty segment, `first`, and `sec/ond`. But why would you consider `sec/ond` not being a valid segment? Not valid for what? For being interpreted as a file (regular file or directory) in a file system?

Comment: @Gumbo - think of CMS where different path segments resolve to different CMS entities. I need to validate whether user-entered path segment is syntactically correct.

Comment: @mindas: Then what do you consider the correct syntax for path segments?

Comment: @Gumbo - see above, I given at least three examples (also hence my question about _incorrect_, or failing ones)

Comment: @mindas: I guess unless you can clearly say what these segments are used for any suggestion would be vague (unless you only allow such a strict set like alphanumeric characters only).

Comment: @Gumbo, as I said, each path segment is mapped to a resource in CMS system. You can think of it as "page" entity, if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @mindas: And how are these resources or entities identified? What’s wrong with identifying it with `sec/ond`?

Comment: @Gombo - absolutely nothing. What I want is to know whether there exist some resources that, according to RFC, cannot be a result of unescaping.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret the specification in the same way you do; that is, `sec%2Fond` is a single path segment. (But—anyone who creates a URI with a segment like that should be punished severely!)

The problem you are wrestling with is that the un-escaping process is lossey; you cannot round-trip from escaped URI to un-escaped `String` and back to the original escaped URI. There's no way around this; you have to get hold of the escaped URI before any "helpful" processing discards that critical information.

You can read §2.1 for details on the handling of non-ASCII characters, but my understanding is that the escaping rules in RFC 2396 apply to an octet string (bytes) *after* the URI character string has been character-encoded. How the character encoding is performed may be specified by the scheme; there is no general method.

Comment: Finding correct resource to serve after lossy unescaping is a different problem, I did not want to pollute this question, this only deals with the validation part :)

Answer (score 2):

> So, for example, /foo is a valid path segment but /fo?o isn't because of non-escaped ?. To correct the above example, the path segment should be written as /fo%3Fo.

Correct

> This also means that URL http://foo.com/first/sec%2fond would resolve to two unescaped path segments, /first and /sec/ond, and the latter has not only has to be treated as a single segment rather than two separate ones but is also syntactically valid (as an unescaped path segment).

Correct.  There are many implementations that get this wrong though.

> how about characters above U+00FF, can they not be used in path segments? I thought they were supported, at least in the domain names.

URI escapes (% hex hex) encode bytes.  Not code-points.  You need to know the encoding of the URL.  For example, if the encoding is UTF-8, then codepoint U+1234 is encoded as `%E1%88%B4`.

Percent escapes aren't allowed in domain names.  For international domain names see [RFC 3492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492).